# Make relative positioned div grow up to the left instead of down to the right

Tags: javascript, html, css

The default for a relative positioned div is to grow down and to the right. How do I change it to instead grow up and to the left?

This is what I have tried: https://gyazo.com/ce51c504698395c26cffefb9b74e7e3e?token=5a1b803e5fc76fafc357b9c9fd7e4bbf

Comment: Questions like this will get voted down into oblivion. You need to provide actual code and demonstrate what you've done to date in order to solve the problem. You should start with using google to search for div, html and expand, etc. Try out what you find and then come back and update the question with more details.

Comment: Please provide what you have tried to date. Include HTML and CSS so we can see exactly how you are positioning the element. Provide a [MCVE] and describe precisely what you are having issues with. Also, a `div` by default is `display:block` and takes the entire row, so by default it only expands downwards, unless you change it's display property.

Answer (score 0):

Try to move it with css. Something like:

```
<div id="div"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#div {
position:relative;
top: 0px;
right: 0px; //or with left: XXpx; amount of px you want to move it to the right

}
```

You can also use

```
float: right;
```